# problem with ajax requests with firefox

Tags: jquery

Hello guys
I have a question is there a limited number of ajax requests per page because i created this chat program with several ajax requests (with jquery)but it is causing a problem of slowness that every time i try to write a message a number of letters are missing.
Could this a problem of the requests, the function , the network or the browser itself because it is working fine on safari.

Answer (score 0):

You could watch the traffic in another window using

```
ngrep host 1.2.3.4 and port 80  # where 1.2.3.4 is the server IP address
```

That will show you what's going on at the network level, which might help you track down the problem. And strace can help see what's going on with firefox, if you can find a good limited set of system calls to watch for, so the output isn't overwhelming.

Comment: it would almost have to be the browser, since it works in another browser, all else being equal.

Comment: you'll first need to find out where the problem is. it may actually be a bug in Firefox, but probably not. you may just need to recode your AJAX to work better with Firefox. but all is just speculation until you do some troubleshooting at the network level.